# How to create a new textfile, with specific requirements

Tags: python, text-files, file-writing

I have been stuck on a program for a long time and could really use some help. I have a text file that contains results for 20 people, which I have to use to work with on this program. Each line corresponds to the person name followed by 10 results.

The content of the text file is given below

```
Erik Eriksson 11.47 12.7 10.98 12.04 12.0 12.43 10.47 11.82 10.91 10.37
Anna Andersson 10.02 11.23 13.79 12.44 12.56 11.12 12.68 10.53 13.82 10.26
Olle Olsson 13.45 10.55 12.51 14.29 14.09 10.3 11.8 14.28 13.17 14.06
Eva Enoksson 13.09 14.05 12.47 13.45 11.33 14.91 12.56 10.23 10.56 10.86
Sven Svensson 12.99 12.79 11.4 10.6 12.94 10.02 11.96 14.2 12.35 13.34
Robin Robinsson 14.93 14.92 12.41 14.83 13.77 12.77 10.4 11.76 11.36 11.64
Stina Svensson 13.1 12.32 11.91 10.11 11.27 13.86 11.91 10.83 11.14 11.68
Elsa Enoksson 12.99 14.47 14.6 11.54 14.03 13.8 11.56 14.96 10.63 10.09
Ingrid Istedt 10.85 10.38 11.07 14.75 14.52 12.43 13.25 10.36 10.64 14.33
Gunnar Göransson 10.27 13.25 11.47 12.38 12.82 10.32 14.77 10.72 13.17 13.61
Hanna Hansson 11.88 12.79 11.57 14.51 10.41 13.43 13.83 14.69 10.87 11.22
Mats Matsson 13.95 12.64 10.03 14.11 10.6 10.31 10.65 12.72 11.07 11.6
Maria Malmberg 13.66 12.85 11.67 13.06 11.57 13.64 11.95 12.54 11.07 10.47
Vera Valfridsson 14.53 13.02 11.02 11.39 10.07 10.81 10.01 11.24 13.63 13.2
Astrid Adamsson 12.84 11.91 13.34 12.01 12.1 13.2 10.19 11.8 14.49 12.83
Erik Einarsson 14.03 10.78 14.56 10.13 11.98 10.89 11.27 12.7 12.15 14.98
Rune Robertsson 12.11 14.22 13.75 14.88 10.93 13.41 14.75 13.62 11.44 13.24
Mona Månsson 11.9 10.77 13.95 13.9 10.1 12.26 14.69 12.94 11.7 14.14
Martin Martinsson 10.95 14.0 10.18 10.74 10.77 12.3 14.62 11.51 14.92 12.15
Willy Wik 12.78 13.43 10.83 12.39 10.43 12.12 13.84 10.35 13.99 14.1
```

I need to make a program that writes some text like the example below for each person into a new textfile.

Output: (link of output as screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhiyo.jpg)

```
Albin Augustsson
Result: 10.55 11.33 12.44 13.55 14.77 14.99 15.66 16.88 17.99 18.12 
Max: 18.12
Min: 10.55
Median: 14.61

Vera Valfridsson
Result: 10.01 11.33 12.44 13.55 14.77 14.99 15.66 16.88 17.99 18.01
Max: 18.01
Min: 10.01
Median: 14.61
```

How could the flowchart look for this program?

Comment: I don't quite follow why you are opening the file to read again or why this is done in your loop. You should open the file to write before the loop and then write to the file inside your loop as you go.

Comment: It's basically an earlier program that was required for this assignment.  What is requested now is what builds upon it. Maybe I should just delete the code if it causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share how your input file looks like? I'm asking because if it's a csv or if there's a way you can convert the text file into a csv file, you can simply read this file in pandas, making it a pandas dataframe.

Then all you need to do is apply pandas min, max and median functions to return the values for you.

Comment: Hi, didn't quite understand exactly what you meant but hope it was the textfile that needs to be read. Here is a link of how the txt file looks like: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xmbcnt98